# How to login a user programatically in Symfony3 only by it's user_id?

Tags: symfony

I have a user_id. 
Using this user_id, I have found the corresponding user object. 
But I want to login this user.
Is it  possible to login this user using its user_id value only?

Comment: Feel free to give more details...

Comment: i just want to login user only by user_id

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be something like:

```
public function loginUser(Request $request, UserInterface $user)
{
    $firewallName = 'whatever';
    $securityTokenStorage = $this->get('security.token_storage');
    $eventDispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');

    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $firewallName, $user->getRoles());

    $securityTokenStorage->setToken($token);

    $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);

    $eventDispatcher->dispatch(SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN, $event);
}
```

But I would strongly suggest you take the time to understand what is happening here instead of doing a copy/paste.  This sort of stuff can be tricky.

Comment: what is behind this UsernamePasswordToken() function?

Comment: It is not a function, it is a class.  The Symfony security system does not deal directly with a user but rather a token.  Ultimately this token is stored in the session and survives between requests hence keeping the user logged in.  Again, you will need to understand this sort of stuff for the code to work.  Start with reading the security section in the documentation.